# Angular Material component styles are not working

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, angular-material

I have installed Angular Material to one of my Angular apps and the styles of the components are not working although I have added the styles link in my angular.json file. This is what the styles array of the angular.json file looks like:

```
    "styles": [
      "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
      "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
      "src/styles.css"
    ],
```

I tried switching the styles file paths up and down as shown below.

```
    "styles": [
      "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
      "src/styles.css",
      "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    ],
```

When I move the Bootstrap path to the end of the array, Material styles work, but Bootstrap stops working.

My CLI and app information is as follows:

```
Angular CLI: 11.0.0-rc.0
Node: 12.16.3
OS: darwin x64

Angular: 11.0.0-rc.0
... animations, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router
Ivy Workspace: Yes

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1100.0-rc.0
@angular-devkit/build-angular   0.1100.0-rc.0
@angular-devkit/core            11.0.0-rc.0
@angular-devkit/schematics      11.0.0-rc.0
@angular/cdk                    10.2.5
@angular/material               10.2.5
@schematics/angular             11.0.0-rc.0
@schematics/update              0.1100.0-rc.0
rxjs                            6.6.3
typescript                      4.0.3
```

Please help me fix this issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**in your styles.ccs file add these two lines:**

```
@import "~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";
```

And yes, you can use both angular material and bootstrap.
:)

Comment: This worked, thank you so much! But do you know the reason why it doesn't work when I use these paths in angular.json file?

Answer (score 0):

Hello @Shafkhan it is very not advised to mix up the css frameworks. Because they can have conflicting css. In my humble opinion, you should choose between Angular material or bootstrap.

Comment: Thank you, but I have used this in all my other apps. I updated my CLI only for this app and it gives me this error now.

Comment: Then it would be a very useful information to provide the combination of working versions (Angular + angular material + bootstrap) and the combination of not working versions.
Moreover some logs or accurate isolated screenshot example of what you expect/see would help as well.

Comment: @CélianGarcia I have used angular material, bootstrap and ngbootstrap in same project. and none of them has conflicting css. :) So, it's okay to use them together

Comment: Okay Tina :) it sounded painful to maintain to me. Moreover, in term of design, you have to be careful that the look and feel is still consistent. I guess it depends what features you are using from each of them !